# autocomplete attribute rendered not working primefacees

Tags: java, primefaces, autocomplete

I have found a big issue in `Primefaces 5.3`
I have made this already several times but now it is not working anymore.
In My Project I Have some autocomplete tags. They are Working fine, but when I set the rendered option to false and want to show them if some options made. They not working. And they are not calling the query functions for the result list.

I cannot post the hole source code because they have more than 2500 lines of code.

XHTML - File :

```
 <p:dialog widgetVar="createTourdatDlg" id="createTourdatDlg" dynamic="true" header="Tourdat erstellen" width="450">
    <h:panelGrid id="createTourdatPanel" columns="2">
    <p:outputLabel value="Kurzbezeichnung:"/>
    <p:inputText value="#{tourdatenBean.kurzbezeichnung}"/>

    <p:outputLabel value="Tabellen Referenz:"/>
    <p:selectOneButton value="#{tourdatenBean.tabellenReferenz}">
        <p:ajax listener="#{tourdatenBean.test()}" update="@([id$=createTourdatPanel])"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Tourdat Krieger" itemValue="KR" >
        </f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Tourdat Karg" itemValue="KG"/>
    </p:selectOneButton>                


    <p:outputLabel value="Tourdat :"/>
    <p:autoComplete active="#{tourdatenBean.showTourdatvdd}" rendered="#{tourdatenBean.showTourdatvdd}" id="ddtourdatv1" dropdown="true" forceSelection="true" converter="tourdatvConverter" value="#{tourdatenBean.tourdat}" 
                        completeMethod="#{tourdatenBean.tourdatenMB.listZuweisbareTourdat}" var="Tourdatv" itemValue="#{Tourdatv}" itemLabel="#{Tourdatv.trbeze.trim()}" >
    </p:autoComplete>
```

Managed Bean for query List:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class TourdatenMB {

@EJB UmladungenManager      umladungenManager;
@EJB DepotManager           depotManager;
@EJB SubunternehmenManager  subunternehmenManager;
@EJB TafRefPManager         tafRefPManager;
@EJB TourdatenManager       tourdatenManager;
@EJB TourdatvManager        tourdatvManager;
@EJB FahrzeugeManager       fahrzeugeManager;
@EJB TourdatkrManager       tourdatkrManager;

private List<Tourdaten>         listTourdaten = null;
private List<Tourdatv>          listTourdatv = null,
                                listZuweisbareTourdat = null;
private List<Tourdatkr>         listTourdatenkr = null;
private List<Fahrzeuge>         listFahrzeuge = null;
private List<Subunternehmen>    listSubunternehmen = null;
private List<Depot>             listDepot = null;
private List<Umladung>          listUmladung = null;
private List<Tafrefp>           listTourart = null, 
                                listRegion = null,
                                listTourklasse = null,
                                listLieferklasse = null,
                                listFahrzeugklasse = null;
private Fahrzeuge               selectedFahrzeug = null;
private Depot                   startDepot = null,
                                zielDepot = null;

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    updateListen();
}

public void updateListen(){
    listTourdaten = tourdatenManager.getAll();
    listTourdatv = tourdatvManager.getAll();
    listFahrzeuge = fahrzeugeManager.getAll();
    listSubunternehmen = subunternehmenManager.getAll();
    listDepot = depotManager.getAll();
    listUmladung = umladungenManager.getAll();
    listTourart = tafRefPManager.getAllTourarten();
    listRegion = tafRefPManager.getAllRegionen();
    listTourklasse = tafRefPManager.getAllTourklassen();
    listLieferklasse = tafRefPManager.getAllLieferklassen();
    listFahrzeugklasse = tafRefPManager.getAllFahrzeugklassen();
    listZuweisbareTourdat = updateZuweisbareTourdatv();
    listTourdatenkr = tourdatkrManager.getAll();
}

public List<Tourdatv> updateZuweisbareTourdatv(){

    List<Tourdatv> tempListTourdatv = tourdatvManager.getAll();
    if(listTourdaten != null){
        for(Tourdaten t : listTourdaten){
            Tourdatv temptv = null;
            for(Tourdatv tv : tempListTourdatv)
            if(t.getTourdatv().getTrnumm().equals(tv.getTrnumm()) ){
                temptv = tv;
            }
            if(temptv != null)
                tempListTourdatv.remove(temptv);    
        }
        return tempListTourdatv;
    }
    else
        return tempListTourdatv;
}

public List<Tourdatv> listZuweisbareTourdat(String query){
    System.out.println("Testing DD");
    if( query.equals("")){
        return listZuweisbareTourdat;
    }
    else{
        List<Tourdatv> tempList = new ArrayList<Tourdatv>();
        for(Tourdatv tv : listZuweisbareTourdat){
            if(tv.getTrbeze().trim().toUpperCase().startsWith(query.toUpperCase()))
                tempList.add(tv);
        }
        return tempList;
    }

}
// ----- Setter / Getter -----
.....
```

Managed Bean for setting rendered to true and false

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class TourdatenBean {

@EJB TourdatenManager tourdatenManager;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{tourdatenMB}")
private managedBeans.TourdatenMB tourdatenMB;

private String  kurzbezeichnung;
private int anzahlStopps;
private float   kmBisDepot,
                kmGesammt,
                kmLetzterKunde;
private Time    startZeit,
                endZeit;
private Depot   startDepot,
                zielDepot;
private Fahrzeuge   fahrzeug;
private Tafrefp     tourKlasse,
                    lieferKlasse,
                    region,
                    tourArt;
private List<Umladung>  umladungen;
private Tourdatv    tourdat;
private Integer     tourdatkrId;
private String      tabellenReferenz;       // Auswahl für die Referenzierung auf Tourdatv oder TourdatKR
private Boolean     showTourdatvdd = false;

public void test(){
    System.out.println("Test");
    System.out.println("tabellenReferenz:" + tabellenReferenz);
    if(tabellenReferenz.equals("KG"))
        showTourdatvdd = true;
    else 
        showTourdatvdd = false;

    System.out.println(getTourdatenMB().listZuweisbareTourdat("").size());
}
public void create(){
    Tourdaten t = new Tourdaten();
    t.setAnzahlStopps(anzahlStopps);
    t.setEndzeit(endZeit);
    t.setFahrzeug(fahrzeug);
    t.setKmBisdepot(kmBisDepot);
    t.setKmGesammt(kmGesammt);
    t.setKmLetzterkunde(kmLetzterKunde);
    t.setKurzbezeichnung(kurzbezeichnung);
    t.setLieferKlasse(lieferKlasse);
    t.setRegion(region);
    t.setStartDepot(startDepot);
    t.setStartzeit(startZeit);
    t.setTourArt(tourArt);
    t.setTourdatv(tourdat);
    t.setTourKlasse(tourKlasse);
    t.setZielDepot(zielDepot);
    tourdatenManager.create(t);
    t.setTourdatkrId(tourdatkrId);
    clear();
    getTourdatenMB().updateListen();
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.addCallbackParam("window", "createTourdatDlg");
}

public void delete(int id){
    Tourdaten t = tourdatenManager.find(id);
    tourdatenManager.remove(t);
    clear();
    getTourdatenMB().updateListen();
}

public void clear(){
    kurzbezeichnung = null;
    anzahlStopps= 0;
    kmBisDepot= 0.0F;
    kmGesammt= 0.0F;
    kmLetzterKunde= 0.0F;
    startZeit= null;
    endZeit= null;
    startDepot= null;
    zielDepot= null;
    fahrzeug= null;
    tourKlasse= null;
    lieferKlasse= null;
    region= null;
    tourArt= null;
    umladungen= null;
    tourdat= null;
    tourdatkrId = null;
    tabellenReferenz = null;

}
```

when I not using the rendered attribute of the autocomplete everything is working fine. And I used this kind of code in several projects and there it is working with the rendered attribute. I hope somebody can help my to find my mistake.
Thanks

Comment: Why are the beans @ApplicationScoped? Could you try with appendTo="@(body)" on the dialog and put a h:form inside it. Also, nothing in the browser console?

Comment: nothing in the browser console. the javascript is working fine.

Comment: [mcve} is what is needed

Comment: I have it now tested with your idea but it is still the same. it is not working. when i press on the drop down button nothing happents. but when i put the rendered attribute away it is working fine

Comment: what do you mean with [mcve} ?

Comment: You should not post the whole code anyway, but a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok Thank you for the reply.... have done what you said.
I have found the mistake i made.....
i have imported the wrong ApplicationScoped